# Magento Multishipping checkout will not pull through Shipping Method

Tags: php, magento, checkout

I have a problem with my Mulitple Shipping Checkout in Magento 1.6.1. When a customer proceeds through the checkout and they come to the Shipping.phtml page where they chose a shipping option and cost they can continue to the billing stage of the checkout without chosing a shipping method. I would like to make this a required field in the checkout. However another problem is that even if the customer choses a Shipping Method it is not added to the grand total at the end of the checkout. Does anyone have any ideas about why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Just because you might be using CSS in your site, this doesn't make your issue CSS-related and thus you shouldn't use the tag. Removed both `CSS` and `HTML` tags.

Answer (score 0):

The shipping method is a required field and its cost will be added to the totals and the end of the checkout in a default Magento installation. I guess you have one or more custom edits within your templates or have some extension installed, that produces that behavior. Switch back to default template and temporary disable non-core extensions to see if it works as expected. Afterwards re-enable deactivated extensions one-by-one.

Comment: Hi feeela thank you for your reply. Im pretty new to Magento so im not exactly sure how to switch the template back to default. Do you have any idea of hwo to do this easily? Do you mean the hole stores template or just the multishipping checkouts template?

Comment: You can specify which templates are used at `YOUR_SHOP_DOMAIN/admin/system_config/edit/section/design/` under "Themes". Just empty those inputs but remember, which was filled with what; clear the cache and test the checkout again…

Comment: Hi feeela I tryed the above and it did not make a difference. The same just happened. By any chance do you have any other ideas?